# Oracle JDK Update 5 (1.7.0_05) not working on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11. EOFException while connecting to Javaspace Blackboard (JINI)

Tags: java, linux, oracle

We are trying to run a process (broker) from a *SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11* (java-1_7_0-ibm) which connects to a *Javaspace Blackboard (JINI)* deployed on another linux machine. (*CentOs* with *Open JDK "1.7.0_05-icedtea"* version)

```
Stack Trace :
INFO: Starting broker
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:259)
            at net.jini.jeri.BasicInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(BasicInvocationHandler.java:653)
            at net.jini.jeri.BasicInvocationHandler.invoke(BasicInvocationHandler.java:528)
            at com.sun.jini.reggie.$Proxy0.lookup(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.jini.reggie.RegistrarProxy.lookup(RegistrarProxy.java:128)
            at edu.vt.ndssl.blackboard.JiniSpaceService.findSpace(JiniSpaceService.java:372)
            at edu.vt.ndssl.blackboard.JiniSpaceService.<init>(JiniSpaceService.java:74)
            at edu.vt.ndssl.blackboard.JavaSpaceBlackboard.<init>(JavaSpaceBlackboard.java:31)
            at edu.vt.ndssl.blackboard.BlackboardFactory.make(BlackboardFactory.java:28)
            at edu.vt.ndssl.broker.Broker.<init>(Broker.java:53)
            at edu.vt.ndssl.broker.Broker.main(Broker.java:231)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
            at com.sun.jini.logging.Levels.createLevel(Levels.java:142)
            at com.sun.jini.logging.Levels.<clinit>(Levels.java:52)
            at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:237)
            ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2667)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1387)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1984)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1867)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1419)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:420)
            at com.sun.jini.logging.Levels.createLevel(Levels.java:138)
            ... 13 more
```

Same code works fine with Java 1.6 version upto 26.
I am looking for a correct version of Java to be installed on the *SUSE Linux Enterprise Server* which will be compatible with this OS and also equivalent to the *Oracle JDK Update 5* or *Open JDK Version 1.7.0_05 (icedtea)*.

Comment: Any known bugs related to this fixed in any of those products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the root cause of the problem is that Oracle has made an incompatible change to the serialization format of the `com.sun.jini.logging.Levels` class.  The change reportedly happened in Oracle JDK 1.6.0_38 and JDK 1.7.0_13, and has presumably made it into recent OpenJDK versions as well.

This problem has manifested in a variety of projects that use JINI.  Examples:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RIVER-415 + https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RIVER-416.
- https://cloudifysource.zendesk.com/entries/23079726-bootstrap-localcloud-not-working-Could-not-initialize-class-com-sun-jini-logging-Levels

More examples can be found by searching for "com.sun.jini.logging.Levels EOFException".

---

I can't say what the solution is / would be for you, but I have a couple of ideas:

Avoidance: I think you can avoid the problem if you don't mix pre and post-change JVM versions in your application network.

If you need to upgrade your application JVMs, I suggest that you upgrade them all, and then do a complete shutdown/restart of your JINI applications and services.

Fix your applications: It appears that the Apache River project fixed the problem by modifying the JINI code.  As the [issue ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RIVER-416) says:

> The com.sun.jini.logging.Levels class produces a RuntimeException with the latest version of Java (both 1.6 and 1.7). The issue surrounds creation of custom java.util.logging.Level. The current implementation uses a ClassReplacingObjectOutputStream and the LevelData approach. By removing this approach and creating a subclass of java.util.logging.Level the issue gets resolved.

The [issue ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RIVER-416) has a lot of discussion on the best way to do this, proposed patches and links to the checkin where they actually implemented the fix.